# Make Jquery UI autocomplete responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to display autocomplete list responsive

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".search_textbox").autocomplete({
        source: "../autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 1,
        create: function (event, ui) {   
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>').append('<div class="autocompleteStore">' + item.key +
                    '</div><div class="autocompleteCashback"><span class="cashback-icon"></span><span class="cashback-text"> <span class="ac_cashback">'+item.desc+'</span></span></div>').appendTo(ul).css("position", "static");;
            };
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            var label = ui.item.label;
            var data = $('#searchtext').val(label);
            document.searchfrm.submit();
        } 

    });             

});

</script>
```

**I tried the following solution to move the div to the autocomplete textbox **

[Jquery UI autocomplete. How to write the results inside a div using innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018669/jquery-ui-autocomplete-how-to-write-the-results-inside-a-div-using-innerhtml)

**Solution for moving the div to respective div was following**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".search_textbox").autocomplete({
        source: "../autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 1,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $("#auto-complete").show();
            return $('<li>')
            .append('<div class="autocompleteStore"></div><div class="autocompleteCashback"><span class="cashback-icon"></span><span class="cashback-text"> <span class="ac_cashback"></span></span></div>')
                .appendTo("#auto-complete")
                .css("position", "static");

        select: function (e, ui) {
            var label = ui.item.label;
            var data = $('#searchtext').val(label);
            document.searchfrm.submit();
        } 

    });             

});

</script>
```

But this solution make it responsive but, data is not coming in open function. So I have decided to use create function and display data responsive.

Comment: Go with this link, may be it will help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332262/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-for-different-values/34332476#34332476

Comment: Hello @Neeraj thanks for answer, but I want to display data in another div with open function